# Difference between bitwise operators in php and ruby

Tags: php, ruby, hex, bitwise-operators, hexdump

I have such code in PHP:

```
$b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);

$file = fopen('message.dat', 'w') or die('cannot create file');
fwrite($file, $b1);
fclose($file);
```

hexdump shows me:

```
$ hexdump message.dat
```

0000000 3231 0039
0000003

The same code in Ruby:

```
b1 = 0x08 | (0x1 & 0x0f)
File.open('message.dat', 'w') { |file| file.write b1 }
```

hexdump shows me:

```
$ hexdump sockets/message.dat
```

0000000 0039
0000001

b1 should be equal to 9 (decimal). Hex ASCII gives 39. Ok.
But PHP gives extra 3231 hex.

Why?

**PS**. I want to convert PHP code to Ruby. This is WebSocket server.
PHP code works properly. 
File output just only for debugging.

Comment: "b1 should be equal to 9 (decimal)."  What? No, not with the php code you've posted. `0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f) = 0x81`. And that 129 in decimal. And if written in ascii (.e. the three characters `1`, `2` and `9`) that's the byte sequence `31 32 39`.

Comment: You have `0x08` in your Ruby code but `0x80` in your PHP code. Is that the problem?

Comment: 9 in case `b1 = 0x08 | (0x1 & 0x0f)` . Yes, `0x08` in Ruby and `0x80` in PHP. Oh, damned inattentiveness :) Thank you